# BST - find number of elements

Tags: c++

Is there a way to find the number of elements in the binary search tree?

```
struct node
{
    node *p, *left, *right;
    int key;
};
```

This is my node's structure, p pointer is pointing to the parent element.

I need to find that number to allocate memory for searching the tree and returning an array with all elements.

I've came up with something like this:

```
int numberOfElements(node *root, int count = 0)
{
    if(root)
    {
        numberOfElements(root->left, ++count);
        numberOfElements(root->right, ++count);
    }
    return count + 1;
}
```

But well, it shows some random results :P For "1, 2" is displays 2, for "1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7" it displays 3 etc...

I want to do this inside one function, that's why count is an argument here.

How can I do this?

Comment: Remember to pass count by reference.

Comment: Or save the return value and make a sum of them.

Comment: You seem to `return` something from your function. I wonder where such a thing could be useful. If we only could call a function and then look at this value somehow, and perhaps save it for future reference...

Comment: The most efficient method is to have a counter in the tree's root node.  Increment it when inserting and element and decrement it when removing an item.  Very easy to return to the number of items in the tree.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need the second argument:

```
int numberOfElements(node *root) {
    if (root) {
        return 1 + numberOfElements(root->left) + numberOfElements(root->right);
    } else {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't seem to use the return value of `numberOfElements` at all.
This version might work:

```
int numberOfElements(node *root)
{
    if(root)
    {
        return numberOfElements(root->left) + 
               numberOfElements(root->right) + 1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Generally, the size of such a tree should be recorded in a field, and gets updated every time you modify the tree. No one expects O(N) running time just to find the size of a tree.